# How do I repeat a rectangle as a header on every page in SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have the following RDL setup: a single rectangle that contains 3 elements (an image, and 2 textboxes). Underneath the rectangle, I have multple tablixes, lets say 3 for now, but this number will increase or decrease dynamically as I am constructing the RDL markup with XML within my .net app. Each tablix will have it's own unique dataset (data and columns differs between the tablixes).
In order to render each tablix on a new page, I went ahead and added a PageBreak:End on each tablix, except the last one. Now, I need the rectangle to be repeated on each page, but how do I do this? I thought that maybe the RepeatWith property could be used, but this only allows a single selected data region. So, the rectangle rendered on page 1 and page 3 (not on page 2).

Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use the report's **Header**? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220421.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could place the rectangle in the report header to repeat on each page:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/selvar/2010/12/27/report-headers-and-footers-with-microsoft-sql-server-reporting-services/